# Comparing two T-SQL tables for diffs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two instances of the same database.  The first db represents data from today, the second data from 6 months ago.  I need to find differences for a subset of entries in a specific table.

For entries with ids that are in both tables, I'd like to find a way to view only the rows that aren't identical.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the close request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE ISNULL(t1.field1,'') <> ISNULL(t2.field1,'')
      OR ISNULL(t1.field2,'') <> ISNULL(t2.field2,'')
      OR ...
```

To produce long WHERE part you can use this function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE compareTables
    @db1    NVARCHAR(100),
    @table1 NVARCHAR(100),
    @db2    NVARCHAR(100),
    @table2 NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @where NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @where = ''

    SELECT @where = @where + 'ISNULL(t1.' + name + ','''') <> ISNULL(t2.' + name + ','''') OR ' 
    FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table1)

    SET @where = SUBSTRING(@where,1,LEN(@where)-3)

    SET @cmd = 'SELECT t1.id FROM ' + @db1 + '.' + @table1 + ' t1 '
    SET @cmd = @cmd + 'INNER JOIN ' + @db2 + '.' + @table2 + ' t2 ON t1.id = t2.id '
    SET @cmd = @cmd + 'WHERE ' + @where

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
END
GO
```

Example usage:

```
EXEC compareTables 'db1_name','dbo.table1','db2_name','dbo.table1'
```

Remember to put schema in the table name.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid you'd say that.

Comment: Don't forget to test for NULL

Comment: Not good? More requirements? Just say, anything can be done here at SO ;-)

Comment: The tables are quite big so I assume that this won't perform very well.  I was hoping for some kind of advanced function that could hash rows or something.  This is however a usable solution and I thank you for it.

Comment: You can generate this big WHERE statement using Dynamic SQL. Give me few minutes, maybe I'll produce something.

Comment: I've added sp to generate statement for you.

Comment: It is almost correct, but not completely so. NULL and '' are different values, and your ISNULL(t1.field1,'') does not distinguish between them

Comment: Here is a suggestion to take not_nullable and numeric values into account (tables in the same datbase here, add db1 and db2 if needed):
 SELECT @where = (at)where + CASE WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN
't1.' + name + ' <> t2.' + name + ' OR ' 
WHEN precision = 0 THEN
'ISNULL(t1.' + name + ','''') <> ISNULL(t2.' + name + ','''') OR ' 
ELSE
'ISNULL(t1.' + name + ',-999999) <> ISNULL(t2.' + name + ',-999999) OR ' 
END 
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID((at)table1)
(I was not allowed to use more than one @ variable, since SO interpreted them as user names. Sorry for the (at):s.)

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but:

```
SELECT *
 from Table1
except select *
 from Table2
```

will list all rows in Table1 that are not present in Table2,

```
SELECT *
 from Table2
except select *
 from Table1
```

will show all in Table2 that are not in Table1, and

```
SELECT *
 from Table1
intersect select *
 from Table2
```

will show all rows that are identical in both tables. If any colums are known to vary between tables, specify only those columns you need to compare.

Answer (score 4):

From your text, I think you say there is an ID that can be used for matching rows.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id 
WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(t1.*) <> BINARY_CHECKSUM(t2.*)
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: BINARY_CHECKSUM doesn't allow the asterisk "*" symbol for all fields. I get "Incorrect syntax near '*'" [asterisk] in 2008R2. It would have been a very nice comparison, if it had worked.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784(v=sql.105).aspx says it's supported in 2008R2. Is there an other problem with the query perhaps?

Comment: You are right: the asterisk _is_ allowed, but the table names are obviously not not allowed. I guess the BINARY_CHECKSUM with (asterisk) generates a checksum for all of the fields, i.e. for the joined tables combined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038338/using-binary-checksum-with-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TableDiff.exe utility that comes with SQL Server 2005 and above.

You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx).

Comment: THis is quite an impressive tool.  I was however hoping for something that can be done within T-SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

for SQL Server 2005 and up try something like this:

```
declare @CurrentTable table (pk int, valuedata varchar(5))
declare @oldtable table (pk int, valuedata varchar(5))

insert into @CurrentTable values (1,'aa')
insert into @CurrentTable values(2,'bb')
insert into @CurrentTable values(3,'cc')
insert into @CurrentTable values(4,'dd')
insert into @CurrentTable values(5,'ee')

insert into @oldtable values(1,'aa')
insert into @oldtable values(1,'bb')
insert into @oldtable values(3,'zz')
insert into @oldtable values(7,'aa')
insert into @oldtable values(8,'qq')

select pk,valuedata  from @CurrentTable
except
select pk,valuedata from @oldtable
```

OUTPUT

```
pk          valuedata
----------- ---------
2           bb
3           cc
4           dd
5           ee

(4 row(s) affected)
```

if SQL Server 2000 or older try something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.*
    FROM YourTableCurrent             c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOld  o ON c.id=o.id
    WHERE ISNULL(c.IntCol,-2147483648)!=ISNULL(o.IntCol,-2147483648)
        OR ISNULL(c.varcharCol,'||null||')!=ISNULL(o.varcharCol,'||null||')
        OR ISNULL(c.DatetimeCol,'01/01/1753')!=ISNULL(o.DatetimeCol,'01/01/1753')
        ....
UNION
SELECT
    o.*
    FROM YourTableOld                     o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableCurrent  c ON c.id=o.id
    WHERE c.id IS NULL
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you are aware, there is a terrific third party tool that you can buy to do this sort of thing for SQL Server databases called SQL Data Compare. It is sold by red-gate. 
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm?gclid=CKPp-6-Bi50CFQRM5QodtWGl8g

There's a free trial. But it's worth spending the money for.

Comment: It's only fair to add that there's a number of data compare tools out there... (Red Gate's was not my choice). Here is a list updated a few years ago: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1069/sql-server-comparison-tools/