# Using BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a very hacky change tracking excercise using a legacy application.

What I'm planning to do, is store the BINARY_CHECKSUM values of each row in a separate table, to compare against in my app.

Imagine I have 2 tables - TableA, TableB
Both have a ProductID column (So can join the two tables together)

I'm looking for a query something like:

```
SELECT a.ProductID, a.BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)AS Hash1, b.BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS Hash2 FROM 
TableA a
JOIN
TableB b
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
```

This obviously doesn't work... but something along those lines, so the result would be (for example)

ProductID | Hash1       | Hash2
1234      | --439419708 | -35860977

Answer (score 1):

you might something try this:

```
with a as (
select BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) as CheckSum,
*
from TableA
),
b as (
select BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) as CheckSum,
*
from TableB
)
select 
a.keyField, a.CheckSum, b.CheckSum
from 
a
full outer join
b
on a.keyField = b.keyField
where a.CheckSum <> b.CheckSum
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT a.ProductID, Hash1, Hash2
FROM (select ProductID, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS Hash1 from TableA a) a
JOIN (select ProductID, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS Hash1 from TableB b) b on ...
```

Your problem is just a syntax problem. Your approach will work.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx a single unqualified star should work.

Comment: thanks.. however the join seems a bit strange - the results are coming back twice...

Comment: sorry.. i should of said, there are a couple of other cols (the productID is non-unique, it's a composite of ProductID|Brand) - i tried adding brand to the select and that's when I get the duplicated results - DISTINCT didn't work either

Comment: Well, a solution that will always work is to specify every single column: BINARY_CHECKSUM(col1, col2, col3, ...)