# How do I find the missing codes between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions, rank

I have two tables:

Table one contains 3 columns:

- spellNUM (unique identifier for a hospital inpatient stay),
- nhsNUM(unique identifier for a patient), and
- diagnosis (for diagnosis codes recorded during a inpatient hospital spell) in april 2020(i.e. one month).

The second table has hospital spell numbers, nhs numbers and diagnoses across all time (circa 10+ years).

My goal is for each spellNUM in table one, to identify what diagnosis codes,from table two, are missing for each patient (NhsNUM)(i.e. not present in the listed spell in table 1).

For example, 
table one:

```
spellNUM/nhsNUM/diagnosisCD
1   /  443  / g111
1    /   443     / y555
1     /   443     / t777
2       / 443    /   a555
2       /  443   /    u777
```

table two:

```
spellNUM/nhsNUM/diagnosisCD
1      /  443   /   g111
1   /     443   /   y555
1    /    443   /   t777
2    /    443   /   a555
2      /   443   /   u777
3   /     443   /   k656
3     /   443    /  u777
3       / 443  /  g111
3      /  443  /  y555
```

For spell 1, in table one, the codes that are missing are a555, u777 and k656 (missing codes from spell 2 & 3 in table 2). Note that some codes in spell 3 (table 2) are the same as those in spell 1 (table 1)(e.g. g111) and so we are not interested in them.

For spell 2 in table one, the missing codes are g111, y555, t777, k656 (from spell 1 and 3 in table two).

I need my output to list the spellNUM, nhsNUM and the distinct missing diagnosis codes.

In this case it would be:

```
spellNUM/nhsNUM/diagnosisCD
1    /  443   /a555
1   /  443  /  u777
1  /   443   / k656
2   /  443   / g111
2   /  443  /  y555
2   /  443 /  t777
2   / 443  / k656
```

I have tried a chunk of ctes and window functions but my efforts have been futile!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: For me, the logic around when a `spellNum` matters and when it does not matter is not clear. I can't tell what the grouping rules are.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is known as a merging problem. Quit often different versions of files need to be [compared/merged](https://github.com/Dirkster99/Aehnlich) in order to find their differences. Your problem is very similar except that you need to compare/merge database tables to see their differences.

Some database systems support [merging directly in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - research the SQL Reference of your system if you want to update one table based on the content of another table.

Here is one of the open source tools I have found using the a search query "merging database tybles" in case you do not want to solve this with a tool:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185498/Comparator-data-sources-comparer

...and here is a SO [solution in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473073/comparing-two-t-sql-tables-for-diffs) should you need a programmatic solution in SQL code.

[Here is the solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9a07f037f5d0504bc283b71cfd1cd79) that I've adapted from the code under the above link:

```
create table table1 (spellNum int, nhsNum int, diagnosisCD varchar(10));
create table table2 (spellNum int, nhsNum int, diagnosisCD varchar(10));

insert into table1 (spellNUM, nhsNUM, diagnosisCD) values
(1, 443, 'g111'),
(1, 443, 'y555'),
(1, 443, 't777'),
(2, 443, 'a555'),
(2, 443, 'u777');

insert into table2 (spellNUM, nhsNUM, diagnosisCD) values
(1, 443, 'g111'),
(1, 443, 'y555'),
(1, 443, 't777'),
(2, 443, 'a555'),
(2, 443, 'u777'),
(3, 443, 'k256'),
(3, 443, 'u777'),
(3, 443, 'g111'),
(3, 443, 'y555');

-- will list all rows in table1 that are not present in table2
SELECT *
 from table1
except select *
 from table2

-- will show all in table2 that are not in table1 
SELECT *
 from table2
except select *
 from table1

-- will show all rows that are identical in both tables.
-- If any colums are known to vary between tables, specify only those columns
-- you need to compare.
SELECT *
 from table1
intersect select *
 from table2
```

and the output is:

```
spellNum    nhsNum  diagnosisCD

spellNum    nhsNum  diagnosisCD
3           443     g111
3           443     k256
3           443     u777
3           443     y555

spellNum     nhsNum  diagnosisCD
1            443     g111
1            443     t777
1            443     y555
2            443     a555
2            443     u777
```

Comment: `Note that some codes in spell 3 (table 2) are the same as those in spell 1 (table 1)(e.g. g111) and so we are not interested in them.` That's not a `MERGE`, or even a list of deltas.

Comment: The statement: 'I need my output to list the spellNUM, nhsNUM and the distinct missing diagnosis codes.' suggests to me that we are looking for a diff which is what I've linked in the last link on T-SQL.

Comment: Look at the desired results. Where are all of the `spellNUM = 3` results that would be present in a simple `MERGE`?

Comment: I mean, you might be right, but I do wish the OP would chime in with some clarification.

Comment: Hi guys- thanks for the responses.   We are looking for the differences between each patient's (nhs number) missing distinct codes (diagnosis CD), when looking at a given spell grain (spell num). For example, if looking at spell 1 we are interested in what codes are present in the other spells (2 and 3) that are not present in spell 1.  In the example above, spell 1 and 2 were in april (the sample month), spell 3 was from outside that period.

Comment: OK, you should be able to find these codes from the above answer which I adapted from the previously linked example. You can obviously use select destinct with the columns you are interested in to customize this further (see comment in SQL code).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
with 
t1 as (select distinct spellNum, nhsNum from table1),
t2 as (select distinct nhsNum, diagnosisCd from table2),
x as (select t1.*, t2.diagnosisCD from t1 cross join t2) 
select * from x
where not exists (select * from table1 y 
where x.spellNum = y.spellNum and 
  x.nhsNum = y.nhsNum and x.diagnosisCD = y.diagnosisCD);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0f4cdd47bcae28dbf0cd1207022a968)

Comment: Thanks! I have never used a cross join before but will have a google!

Comment: The potential issue with the cross join is our tables have thousands of rows (I only gave a few an example), so if I understand cross joins correctly we would end up with millions of rows in the generated table? I will try it tomorrow and let you know how it runs! Is there an alternative to using a cross join?

Comment: Not exactly. You are cross joining distinct spellNumber, nhsNumber (X rows) with distinct nhsNumber, diagnosisCodes (Y rows). Although there are close to 70 thousands ICD 10 codes, for a particular patient your codes should not exceed 5 on the average (diagnosing should not be very loose). I don't know what spellNumber is, if it can be 10 on the average per patient and you have 100 000 patients result is 5 million rows only. This sounds to be a one time job that doesn't need to seek for another way. If you need you still can do in other ways, probably with an outer apply or not exists query.